# How to pass more than just the new value in a change event on an input?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm generating a form with VueJS dynamically from a JSON schema and trying to send the data into my Vuex state.

Here's my code so far (simplified)

```html
<div v-for="field in schema" :key="field.fieldName">
  <div> {{ field.fieldName }} </div>
  <div v-if="field.type==='text'">
    <b-input type="text" @change="onFieldChanged" :placeholder="field.fieldName"></b-input>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my onchange method is:

```js
methods: {
  onFieldChanged (val) {
    // send val to the state to put it in the form object
  }
}
```

Ideally what I'd like is to also be able to send my `v-for`'s `field.fieldName` to define exactly what has been changed. Is there a way to do this?

I imagine another way would be to use `v-model` to associate the fields directly and their values to an object in my `data`, this occurred to me just as I typed this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `v-on` directive provide a `$event` object with the value emitted, so you can use it in template to call the event handler with additional params:

```
<b-input type="text" @change="onFieldChanged($event, field.fieldName)" :placeholder="field.fieldName"></b-input>
```

And:

```
methods: {
  onFieldChanged (val, fieldname) {
    // send val to the state to put it in the form object
  }
}
```